# Camera2 api characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_VERSION); getting null

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am trying to get camera version for my usb hardware camera using Camera2 api.I used characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_VERSION) i am getting null value. Is there any method to get the camera version or any other api so that i can get the version of my camera??.

```
private String getCameraVersion(Context context) {
        String cameraVersion = "";
            
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            
            cameraVersion = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_VERSION);
            
    
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
               
        //Camera.getCameraInfo();
        Log.i(TAG, "Camera version " + cameraVersion);
        return cameraVersion;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[INFO_VERSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics?hl=en#INFO_VERSION) is an optional string that some manufacturers might set, primarily to include within the EXIF TAG_SOFTWARE field of any JPEG images an app might produce.  It's there just to help with debugging, and the manufacturers that include it often include some kind of information about hardware revisions or firmware versions.  But it's not standardized in any way.

The default USB camera HAL for Android doesn't set that field to anything, so it's not surprising it's null.

Comment: Can we get the camera version using opencv??

Comment: I don't really know what version you're looking for, but no, opencv has no particular access to hardware details.

Comment: Thanks for the info eddy will search on android_v4l2_camera if i will get the version there